# Statistics summary table not working with sliders

Tags: python, statistics, bokeh, spyder

I need help with setting up the bokeh app to update my DataTable with sliders interaction
I have about 60 such parameters and about 150 thousand combinations of them.
Importing the excel sheet itself takes about 12 minutes I am trying to fix up some 15 to 20 sliders and trying to play with them to see which of these combinations fall into my criteria based on some engineering filters. i tried plotting graphs it wasn't easy to visualize, thus i am trying to understand the variation by their statistics summary table

Initially, I am trying to filter data based on some engineering conventions and later I am trying to sort out or rank the filtered data and select the best possible combinations which will give me an idea of what range each of 15 parameters should fall in for optimum design
currently, with this code, the table does not show up and sliders don't work
I suspect some issue with the definition of the table and the call back function

I have written the code on the latest Python 3.7 and latest Bokeh 1.2.0 and latest Pandas on Spyder IDE. I tried doing custom JS since I don't really know to programme on JavaScript, I would rather avoid it completely.

> ```
> Data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\vsrigiri\Desktop\app\try.xlsx') 
> df = pd.DataFrame (Data, columns= ['No.','a','z_1', 'z_2','u'])
> dfs = pd.DataFrame(dfs.describe())
> source = ColumnDataSource(dfs)
> a_Slider= RangeSlider(start=min(df['a']), end=max(df['a']), value=(min(df['a']),max(df['a'])), step=1, title='YY in mm')
> z_1_Slider = RangeSlider(start=min(df['z_1']), end=max(df['z_1']), value=(min(df['z_1']),max(df['z_1'])), step=1, title='ZZ')
> def callback(attr,new,old)
>     a_s = a_Slider.value[0]
>     a_e = a_Slider.value[1]
>     z_1_s= z_1_Slider.value[0]
>     z_1_e= z_1_Slider.value[1]
>     dff= pd.DataFrame(df[(df.a >= a_s) & (df.a <= a_e) & (df.z_1 >= z_1_s) & (df.z_1 <= z_1_e) & (df.z_2 >= z_2_s) & (df.z_2 <= z_2_e)& (df.u >= u_s)& (df.u <= u_e)])
>     dft=dff.describe()
>     source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(dft)
> #function ends here   
> a_Slider.on_change("value",callback)
> z_1_Slider.on_change("value",callback)
> table=DataTable(source=source)
> Graphs = row([table])
> Controls1= column([a_Slider,z_1_Slider])
> layout= row(Controls1,Graphs)
> ```

I am expecting the sliders to update the statistics table summary on the screen
on a second priority if you could guide me to write a loop for each of sliders definition and callback
I don't want to repeat every line again and again.

Comment: Can you please submit a minimal reproducible example of the error - your code relies on reading on external data that no one can replicate, and has alot of complexity that may not be relevant.

Comment: @Anthonydouc, I have updated the question to give you more clarity